# Can I get Ray Gun Mark 2 without the Season Pass?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Can I get the Ray Gun Mark 2 if I have purchased Vengeance Map Pack but not the DLC Season Pass? I do not want to have to buy the Season Pass, and I hope that I can get the Ray Gun Mark 2 without it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

From the [wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ray_Gun_Mark_II)

> The Ray Gun Mark II is a wonder weapon that was released alongside the Zombies map, Buried, and is featured in all Zombies maps in Call of Duty: Black Ops II (**only if the player has downloaded the Vengeance map pack**).

Basically, the reason people with the Season Pass get this weapon, is because they have effectively pre-purchased the Vengeance map pack, but anyone who purchases the map pack separately gets it as well, regardless of what they do/don't already have in terms of other map packs.

Comment: I think I should note that no, this is not an elaborate attempt to answer my own question...

Comment: I can confirm, there is in fact two different Bens. @Ben - Should we start calling you both B1 and B2? :P

Answer (score -1):

Yes they do, because people who purchase the DLC was released WITH the ray gun mark 2 not with the season pass. Thereforth, you will receive it. The same goes for the die rise dlc with the peacekeeper assultrifle for multiplayer